# Java: NullPointerException from class.getResource( ... )

Tags: java, classpath

I was writing a small application and when I tried to create an ImageIcon I always got an exception. The exception was caused by this line of code:

```
prayerLevel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon_prayer.png")));
```

Now within my program, the folder /icons/ does exist. I don't know if it makes the difference but the class file is within a package, where as the icons folder is within the project folder (when you would see the bin and src folder).

I have looked around for a bit and I couldn't find a solution that could help me solve the problem. Perhaps any of you guys could help?

Edit: someone asked for my folder hierarchy:

[image: Folder Hierarchy]

I know the class file is not in the same folder as the icons are, but I've made applications where I had to load files from a different folder and doing /folder/ always used to work.

Edit 2:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/icons/icon_prayer.png") == null);
```

Prints true.

Comment: how does the folder hierarchy look like? When you say /icons folder exists, where exactly is it?

Comment: You should probably include the relevant error message - particularly the stack trace - as that will show us where exactly the problem is occurring.

Comment: I figured out why I am getting the NullPointer, but now I cannot figure out why class.getResource( ... ) is null. The file 'icon_prayer.png' is in folder 'icons.'

Comment: is the icons folder on the classpath when the application is run?

Comment: The NPE isn't from `Class.getResource()`, contrary to your title. It results from your failure to check the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the NPE is being thrown from the `ImageIcon` constructor as `getResource` is returning `null`.

Try the following:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/icons/icon_prayer.png")
```

Or:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/icons/icon_prayer.png")
```

Comment: I tried    getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/icons/icon_prayer.png"), no change

Comment: @Martin Tuskevicius: I added another method of retrieval - give it a shot!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know `getResource()` will look into locations of known resources, in other words if the folder `/icons/` is not seen as a resource folder it will not as you had expected. There are two ways of going around this as far as I know:

1) Set icons folder as a resource to the application, then you can use `getResource()` for instance 
`URL css_url = getClass().getResource("/resource/style.css");`

For more info on this option, see http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-classgetresource-load-resource.html

2) Get the icon as a regular file without using `getResource()` method. This is actually adviced in [Swing tutorials on Sun/Oracle own documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) .

> Generally, applications provide their own set of images used as part
>   of the application, as is the case
>   with the images used by many of our
>   demos. You should use the Class
>   getResource method to obtain the path
>   to the image. This allows the
>   application to verify that the image
>   is available and to provide sensible
>   error handling if it is not. When the
>   image is not part of the application,
>   getResource should not be used and the
>   ImageIcon constructor is used
>   directly. For example:
>
> ImageIcon icon = new
>   ImageIcon("images/middle.gif",
>                                  "a pretty but meaningless splat");

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but since I bumped into a similar problem just now...

I'm using Eclipse and I copied a file to the "resources" folder using system commands (`cp`). However, eclipse threw a `NullPointerException` because I didn't refresh the "resources" folder. So the file was there but Eclipse didn't see it.

So in Eclipse: "Package Explorer" -> "resources" -> Mouse right click -> refresh. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Same fix here for IntelliJ IDEA: Build->"Rebuild project" did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I added my music, images, etc to a folder added to the build path.  Then I just used

```
URL url="CurrentClass".class.getClassLoader().getResource("media file name not the path");
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(url.getPath()).getImage());
```

to set the image icon.

Comment: This did the trick. I had added my Resources/data folder to the class path, but I was just using class.getResource instead of class.getClassLoader().getResource. Which doesn't work if you are in the default package.

Comment: Nice article for this is here 
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/

Answer (score -3):

The only thing that can throw a `NullPointerException` in this line of code is the first `.`, which means that `prayerLevel` is null.

Comment: This isn't true. The constructor `ImageIcon(URL)` will throw a NPE if the provided URL is null as the implementation is simply: `public ImageIcon(URL location) { this(location, location.toExternalForm()); }`

Comment: But then the NullPointerException is not caused (directly) by *this* line, but by some line from the constructor.

Comment: That's a moot point. Either way, this would've been clear had the OP included the stacktrace. Note to OP: include the relevant error message!

Comment: The URL provided as an argument for the constructor is null.

Comment: You're right, hence the NPE from the `ImageIcon` constructor.