# Java "main" java.lang.NullPointerException due to ImageIcon in Beans

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I am trying to run an application in netbeans, but regularly getting bellow given error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at Login.<init>(Login.java:36)
at Login.main(Login.java:90)
C:\Users\MyPc\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

The image is used in line 36 as:

```
 btnLogin = new JButton("Login", new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/login.png")));
```

[image]

[image]

> This question is different as already answered questions have been reviewed but none of them are able to solve the issue. Similar questions can be different depending upon particular environment.

Comment: Already been through that question. But couldn't solve my issue at all.

Comment: Exact same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023039/java-nullpointerexception-from-class-getresource

Comment: This means `ClassLoader.getSystemResource("Images/login.png")` returns `null`. Show us your directory structure.