# Java: Can't read Tiff image file

Tags: java, tiff

I'm trying to read an image from a relative path:

```
String fp = "../resources/img/wc/text/039.tiff";
```

The following code succeeds:

```
File fi = new File(getClass().getResource(fp).getPath());
System.out.println("fi: " + fi);
if (fi.exists() && !fi.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("file exists");  // <-- console prints this
}

try {
    img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(fp));
    System.out.println("file read");  // <-- console prints this
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

... but the following code just after it:

```
System.out.println(img.getType());
```

... fails, reporting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ddc.fmwscanner.java.LoadImageApp.ddNextImage(LoadImageApp.java:60)
at com.ddc.fmwscanner.java.LoadImageApp.<init>(LoadImageApp.java:85)
at com.ddc.fmwscanner.main.FmwScanner.main(FmwScanner.java:15)
```

I know the image is valid, because I can open it using non-Java methods.  However, those methods will not open the image from a .jar, so I need to use a pure Java method.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Your path is likely incorrect. Understand that resources start at the class-path, meaning the location of your class files.

Comment: How would I verify an incorrect path?  (ugh, can't post code easily in these comments.)  The following: `System.out.println(getClass().getResource(fp).getPath());` returns an absolute path that is definitely correct.

Comment: Don't treat classpath resources as files. Resources are loaded from the classpath. Files are loaded from the file system. A resource path may not contain .. Read the javadoc.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps, @IlarioPierbattista.  I'll try it with a .jpg.

Comment: @IlarioPierbattista: [perhaps a better duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023039/java-nullpointerexception-from-class-getresource) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796331/jar-embedded-resources-nullpointerexception).

Comment: Wow, .jpg worked fine.  I never would have dreamt a .tiff would be problematic.  Thanks, guys!

Comment: I'll post the solution when I find a means of loading a .tiff.

Comment: For opening 'esoteric' TIFF files, you may find this extension useful: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with loading .tiff files in pure Java.  Installing [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff) did the trick.  Thanks again, especially to @IlarioPierbattista, who directed me to the solution!