# NULL Pointer at InputStreamReader ClassPath

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resources, classpath, inputstreamreader

Hi sadly i just dont get why i receive a nullpointer:

My ResourceLoader class

```
public static String loadResource(String path){
       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       try {
           InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(Class.class.getResourceAsStream(path)) ;
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
           String line = "";
           while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                result.append(line).append("\n");
           }
       }catch (IOException e){
           System.out.println("File nicht gefunden:  " + e);
       }
    return result.toString();
    }
```

This is where i use it

```
shaderProgram.createVertexShader(ResourceLoader.loadResource("shaders/mainVertex.glsl"));
shaderProgram.createFragmentShader(ResourceLoader.loadResource("shaders/mainFragment.glsl"));
```

This is the Exeption i receive

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:167)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at utils.ResourceLoader.loadResource(ResourceLoader.java:13)
    at graphics.Renderer.init(Renderer.java:32)
    at GameEngine.init(GameEngine.java:43)
    at GameEngine.run(GameEngine.java:33)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thank your for looking at it!

Comment: From the exception stack trace, it looks like Class.class.getResourceAsStream(path) is returning null.

Comment: This question seems to be [a duplicate of "NPE from class `getResource`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023039/java-nullpointerexception-from-class-getresource)

Answer (score 1):

As NomadMaker pointed out, the issue lies with the call

`new InputStreamReader(Class.class.getResourceAsStream(path))`

returning a null value (you would have seen this as part of the error message).

This should work for you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "test.txt";
        System.out.println(loadResource(filepath));
    }

    public static String loadResource(String path) {
        InputStream is = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(is));
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("File nicht gefunden:  " + e);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Issues to keep in mind:

1. You need to close the InputStreamReader and BufferedReader when you are done with these. I used a try-with-resources here (refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) if this is new to you).
2. This code assumes that you stored the file you are reading from inside the resources folder. If the file can't be found, a NPE error will be thrown, which I am including in the catch. You may choose to deal with the exception in a different way.
3. This code also assumes that you are working within a static context. If not, use `this.class.getClass()getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)` instead.

Comment: Adding getClassLoader() solved my problem. Thanks Buddy.